# CSS: Scrollable DIV with fieldset

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I was trying to make a scrollable with a fieldset but then the scroll is not working. I'd like to make a scroll because when the text is already not seen the scroll in mozilla firefox is not display also. That's why I'm trying to put or insert a  overflow in fieldset but not working...

Here's the sample code I'm using.

```
<div class = "sam">
<fieldset>
    <legend>test</legend>
    space
    space
<br>    space
<br>    space
</fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sam
{

    overflow:scroll;
}
```

thanks..

Comment: Please use JS fiddle.

Comment: @WayneC.. I already tried that..and that code above came from JS fiddle... and also its not working there..: (

Comment: .sam {height: 30rem; overflow-y: auto;} works for me. overflow scroll make it show scroll always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the height of `.sam`. Otherwise it will just grow with the content. Also, you can use `overflow: auto` to have the scrollbars show up as needed.

Comment: @moderndegree..omg...thank you.. I already forgot how to use CSS.. super Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use overflow must use the height otherwise the form will be extend to outward from the field set